# app name is "null" while request for notifications

Tags: swift2

good morning together :)

i ask the user with the code below, if he/she allow notification of my app:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    if(UIApplication.instancesRespondToSelector(Selector("registerUserNotificationSettings:"))) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil))
    }

    return true
}
```

Problem is that the request will shown, but the app name in this request will be "null"

[[image: 1]]

how can i fix it?
and another question by the way: how can i let request this message on my device again for testing, after i press "OK"?

i use swift 2 ios 8

Answer (score 0):

when i shift my swift 1.2 app to 2.0 i also suffer same problem , i solved it by go to plist file .

**CFBundleDisplayName**
    
look at that key it has empty string tag , just do one thing add this in the string tag **$(PRODUCT_NAME) .** 
so final it look likes:

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
```

it solves my problem hope so it solves yours also.